# PythonOperator not calling the function from another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I am creating a python file which will be in airflow UI. I am exporting a function coming from another python file to my _dag file. I tested the function and it is running perfectly but when i import it in my dag file it is not functioning as expected. the main problem here is the **download_shrpnt** function is not working when imported. I tried adding "()" after download_shrpnt but it is returning 'python_callable must be callable' error. BTW, im running airflow in docker

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
# from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from testsharepointextract import download_shrpnt
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

# reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fl64Y0p7rls


args = {
     'owner': 'test_owner',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023,12,7)
}



dag = DAG(
    dag_id='testsharepointextract_dag',
    default_args=args,
    schedule='@daily'
)


with dag:
    trigger_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'testing',
    python_callable=download_shrpnt,
    dag=dag 
        )
```